# notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged in onDataSetChanged to cause refresh?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-widget

I'm building a widget for my app to get some data from Firestore. The only problem is that while I'm able to get the data successfully initially in onCreate if I leave onDataSetChanged empty.

I belive onDataSetChanged is called after a certain time by the OS to refresh. So I don't want to leave that function blank.

But the problem is that I can't cause the widget to update in onDataSetChanged without infinite recursion because I'm using notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged refresh my widget to show the new documents fetched from Firestore.

So my question is how do I can refresh the widget without notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged inside my callback function for my firebase query?

Thanks

```
    public class TaskWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
   @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new TaskWidgetItemFactory(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }

    class TaskWidgetItemFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {
        public static final String TAG = "TaskWidgetItemFactory";
        private Context context;
        private int appWidgetID;
        private ArrayList<String> tasksArrayList; //tasks I want to show

        public TaskWidgetItemFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
            this.context = context;
            this.appWidgetID = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        void initializeData() {

            Log.d(TAG, "initializeData: I'm being called.....");

            try {

                //Initialize ALL Firebase components
                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                String userId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                final int a = this.appWidgetID;

                Query tasksQuery = db
                        .collection("users/" + userId + "/tasks")
                        .orderBy(Task.FIRESTORE_FIELD_DUE_TIMESTAMP, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                        .orderBy(Task.FIRESTORE_FIELD_PROGRESS, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                        .whereEqualTo(Task.FIRESTORE_FIELD_PARENT_TASK_DOC_ID, null) // only want Parent Tasks
                        ;

                tasksQuery.get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("name"));

                                        Task t = document.toObject(Task.class);

                                        tasksArrayList.add(t.toString()); //add item to show
                                    }

                                    //refresh Widget to show the data.
                                    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = **AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                                    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(a, R.id.task_widget_stack_view);**

                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "initializeData: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            tasksArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            initializeData();//get data
        }


       @Override
        public void onDataSetChanged() {

            tasksArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            initializeData(); //get data  causes infinte recursion b/c of "notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged"
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.d(TAG, "getCount: " + tasksArrayList.size());
            return tasksArrayList.size();
        }

 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (yourList!=null)
{

yourList.clear();

## Perform then opration

}

finally you can call

adapter.notifydatasetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by just getting the data in onDataSetChnaged() by using await.

```
@Override
        public void onDataSetChanged() {
            tasksArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String userId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            Query tasksQuery = db
                    .collection("users/" + userId + "/tasks")
                    .orderBy(Task.FIRESTORE_FIELD_DUE_TIMESTAMP, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                    .orderBy(Task.FIRESTORE_FIELD_PROGRESS, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                    .whereEqualTo(Task.FIRESTORE_FIELD_PARENT_TASK_DOC_ID, null) // only want Parent Tasks
                    ;

            try {

                //wait for data to be collected.
                final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = Tasks.await(tasksQuery.get());

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("name"));

                    Task t = document.toObject(Task.class);
                    tasksArrayList.add(t);
                }

            } catch (ExecutionException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get Tasks.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get Tasks.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
```